# Networks redirect loop due to force ssl

Tags: ssl, meteor

Is there any way to require the HTTPS redirect?

Force SSL package causes a loop...

I am using a demeteorized app on azure...have seen solutions for nginx etc but nothing mentioning this

Answer (score 1):

The force SSL package won't work for an environment where the server is behind a load balancer that redirects to the server as HTTP. As far as the server is concerned, all traffic is HTTP, not HTTPS, so you'll end up with an infinite loop.

In some cases you can look at the headers to see if the request has been downgraded to HTTP locally, but it doesn't always work as expected.

I ended up removing the force SSL package, then used JavaScript in the page template to see if the protocol was HTTP, then redirect the user to HTTPS to prevent the issue.

**Example**

```
<script>
    if (location.protocol.toLowerCase() === 'http:') {
        window.location.href = 'https://example.com' +
                               (location.pathname ? location.pathname : '') +
                               (location.search ? location.search : '');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Would you be able to share sample code snippet of how you checked for HTTP/redirected? And did you then need to put this in every single template...?

Comment: I added an example, which can be placed in the head of your base HTML file. No need to add it to each template.

Comment: Thank you - this helps but doesn't quite solve it (maybe there isn't a solution?) as the server doesn't have control over requiring HTTPS...